# Not sure if my package was installed to target or not in Buildroot

Tags: package, buildroot

I have some issues with 4 customized python libraries I want to add to my target image on Buildroot.

During the make process, Buildroot doesn't raise any error whatsoever, it even raises the `<package> Installing to target` logs and I can't see anything that seems to show a problem. However, I can't find my package anywhere in the target directory so I wonder if it did install it correctly or not, unless I am not looking at the right place... Can someone maybe guide me through this ?

Here are the logs I get during the make process for one of the packages :

```
    >>> python_lxml_cnes 4.6.3 Installing to target
    (cd /home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output
/build/python_lxml_cnes-4.6.3//; _PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME="`{ [ -e /home/mso-aerosat
/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-
gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/python3.9//_sysconfigdata__linux_*.py ] && basename /home/mso-
aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/arm-
buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/python3.9//_sysconfigdata__linux_*.py .py; } || 
true`" PATH="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7
/output/host/bin:/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-
2021.02.7/output/host/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:
/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" PATH="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop
/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin:/home/mso-aerosat
/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/sbin:/usr/local
/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" 
AR="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output
/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-ar" AS="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop
/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-
gnueabihf-as" LD="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-
2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-ld" NM="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop
/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-
gnueabihf-nm" CC="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-
2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" GCC="/home/mso-aerosat
/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-
linux-gnueabihf-gcc" CPP="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot
/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-cpp" CXX="/home/mso-
aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-
buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++" FC="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran" F77="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-
buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran" RANLIB="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace
/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib" 
READELF="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output
/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-readelf" STRIP="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop
/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-
gnueabihf-strip" OBJCOPY="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot
/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy" 
OBJDUMP="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output
/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-objdump" AR_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/ar" 
AS_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/as" CC_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/gcc" GCC_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/gcc" 
CXX_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/g++" LD_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/ld" CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-I/home/mso-
aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/include" 
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-O2 -I/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-
2021.02.7/output/host/include" CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-O2 -I/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop
/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/include" 
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-L/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-
2021.02.7/output/host/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace
/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/lib" FCFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="" 
DEFAULT_ASSEMBLER="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-
2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-as" DEFAULT_LINKER="/home/mso-
aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin/arm-
buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-ld" CPPFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE 
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" CFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE 
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  " CXXFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE 
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  " LDFLAGS="" FCFLAGS=" -Os " FFLAGS=" -Os " 
PKG_CONFIG="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7
/output/host/bin/pkg-config" STAGING_DIR="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace
/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot" 
INTLTOOL_PERL=/usr/bin/perl CXX=no PYTHONPATH="/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-
gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/python3.9/" PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1 _python_sysroot=/home/mso-
aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/arm-
buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot _python_prefix=/usr _python_exec_prefix=/usr  
/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/host/bin
/python setup.py install --no-compile --prefix=/usr --executable=/usr/bin/python 
--single-version-externally-managed --root=/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace
/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/target )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing enough details. Could you push to a public Git repository a branch containing your packages + a configuration that allows to reproduce the issue? With that, I suggest your to ask on the Buildroot mailing list or IRC channel, where you're very likely to help some help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is impossible for me to publish my libraries as it is a work for my company and I can't freely release this kind of work online :/ I can show you my .mk and Conf.in files though if it helps !